# Can not launch TypeScript project

Tags: javascript, typescript, gulp, visual-studio-code

Recently I switched to using Gulp. After struggling a bit I finally managed to succeed compiling my project. Now, I can't launch it, VS Code tells me this:

**Cannot launch program '../src/bootstrap.ts'; setting the 'outFiles' attribute might help.**

When I use tsc to compile and run the app, everything works fine.

Here are my config files:

launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/src/bootstrap.ts",
            "outFiles": ["${workspaceRoot}/lib/**/*.js"],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}"
        }
    ]
}
```

tasks.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "gulp",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": [
        "--no-color"
    ],
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "build",
            "isBuildCommand": true,
            "showOutput": "always",
            "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
        }
    ]
}
```

gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp')
var ts = require('gulp-typescript');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

gulp.task('copy', function () {
    var copyResult = gulp.src('src/templates/*.hbs')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('lib/templates/'));

    return copyResult;
});

gulp.task('compile', function () {
    var tsResult = gulp.src('src/**/*.ts')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(ts({
            module: "commonjs",
            target: "es6",
            noImplicitAny: false,
            typeRoots: ["node_modules/@types"],
            declaration: true,
            experimentalDecorators: true,
            emitDecoratorMetadata: true
        }));

    return tsResult.js
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.', { sourceRoot: function (file) { return file.cwd + '/lib'; } }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('lib'));
});

gulp.task('build', ['copy', 'compile']);
```

And here is the project folder structure:

```
- lib (compiled output)
    - api
    - engine

- src
    - api
    - engine
    - bootstrap.ts

- gulpfile.js
- tsconfig.json
```

So I can't find what's wrong with the **outFiles** setting.

**EDIT**
Ok, I guess I've found what's going on.

This is the js.map file generated by tsc (mapping attribute omitted) :

```
{"version":3,"file":"bootstrap.js","sourceRoot":"","sources":["../src/bootstrap.ts"],"names":[]}
```

And this is the js.map file that gulp generates (mapping and sourceContent omitted):

```
{"version":3,"sources":["bootstrap.ts"],"names":[]}
```

The difference is the obvious absence of relative folder path in the **sources** property. So when I compile with gulp, VSCode can't find the .ts files. So I guess I have to find a way to compile all the files just like tsc does with gulp.

Answer (score 0):

Ok got it!

Adding the code below just before sourcemaps.write() fixes the problem.

```
.pipe(sourcemaps.mapSources(function (sourcePath, file) {
    // source paths are prefixed with '../src/'
    return '../src/' + sourcePath;
}))
```